# How to Setup Transfer Acceleration for S3 on Ruby on Rails Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

Transfer Accelerated S3 bucket allows you to upload/download faster. The setup should be simple in theory:

The endpoint changes from:

```
mybucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

to:

```
mybucket.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com
```

In Ruby on Rails config/storage.yml the environment variables look like this:

```
amazon:

service: S3

access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>

secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>

region: <%= ENV['AWS_REGION'] %>

bucket: <%= ENV['AWS_BUCKET'] %>
```

The problem is the pattern is different, so I can't just change the `AWS_REGION`. There is an extra `.s3` in there.

I wish to learn how to implement S3 transfer acceleration with ROR and Active Storage?

Answer (score 2):

I had to add this below the `bucket`...:

```
use_accelerate_endpoint: true
```